# Constants in a python package

Tags: python, module, constants

I'm writing a python package and am wondering where the best place is to put constants?

I know you can create a file called 'constants.py' in the package and then call them with module.constants.const, but shouldn't there be a way to associate the constant with the whole module? e.g. you can call numpy.pi, how would I do something like that?

Also, where in the module is the best place to put paths to directories outside of the module where I want to read/write files?

Comment: Do you mean a package? A module is one `.py` file, a package is a directory with a `__init__.py` module in it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant package.

Comment: A package is also a module, though. see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__package__

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put them where you feel they can most easily be maintained. Usually that means in the module to which the constants logically belong.

You can always import the constants into the `__init__.py` file of your package to make it easier for someone to find them. If you did decide on a `constants` module, I'd add a `__all__` sequence to state what values are public, then in the `__init__.py` file do:

```
from constants import *
```

to make the same names available at the package level.